# Riverpod: What happened to ProviderRefBase?

Tags: riverpod

Updating from 1.0.0-dev7 to 1.0.0 gives error:
`Undefined class 'ProviderRefBase'.`

Where can I find info on that or how to change code for the new version?

Answer (score 2):

It was renamed. `ProviderRefBase` => `Ref`